# nginx is accessible from ubuntu but not from windows

Tags: nginx

nginx is set up as a reverse proxy on ubuntu server on aws. It is configured to handle 2 domains and route the traffic to a static path and node server running on the same instance  depending on domain name

For e.g. main.com will route to the static path and crm.main.com to the node server

Everything is working as it's supposed to be, nginx routing correctly according to the domain but it's working only on my computer which is Ubuntu but not from other colleagues computers which is having windows 10.

We all are connected to the same network so I don't think it is a firewall issue